# How to rewrite loops properly?

Tags: r, xml, lapply

thematically I would like to convert some data into `XML`. Thanks to some answers on SO I found a proper solution to that issue. However, I would like to change the syntax in order to be able to process large `.csv` files.

Here some data:

```
# Some data
df <-
  read.csv(textConnection('"ID","Name","City","Age"
"1","Steve","Boston",33
"2","Michael","Dallas",45
"3","John","New York",89
"4","Thomas","LA",62
"5","Clint","Paris",30'),
   as.is=TRUE)

 head(df)
    ID    Name     City Age
 #1  1   Steve   Boston  33
 #2  2 Michael   Dallas  45
 #3  3    John New York  89
 #4  4  Thomas       LA  62
 #5  5   Clint    Paris  30

# To create a XML file
library(XML)

# For each employee
# Measure the execution
start.time <- Sys.time()

xml <- xmlTree()
xml$addTag("Document", close=FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  xml$addNode("employee", attrs = c(id = df[i,"ID"]), close = FALSE)
  appNames <- names(df)[names(df) != "ID"]
  for (j in appNames) {
    xml$addNode(j, df[i, j])
  }
  xml$closeTag()
}
xml$closeTag()

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken

# Execution performance
Time difference of 0.0321269 secs

# How the XML looks like
cat(saveXML(xml))
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Document>
  <employee id="1">
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <City>Boston</City>
    <Age>33</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="2">
    <Name>Michael</Name>
    <City>Dallas</City>
    <Age>45</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="3">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <City>New York</City>
    <Age>89</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="4">
    <Name>Thomas</Name>
    <City>LA</City>
    <Age>62</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="5">
    <Name>Clint</Name>
    <City>Paris</City>
    <Age>30</Age>
  </employee>
</Document>
```

Given huge `.csv` I thought it is appropriate to avoid dataframes and uses lists. However dont know whether that is a correct approach:

```
df1<- lapply(unique(df[,1]), function(x) df[df[,1] == x,])

df1[1]

    ID  Name   City Age
 #1  1 Steve Boston  33
```

Now I would like to change structure of the nested loop and use `lappy` on sublists:

```
lapply(df1, function(v)  xml$addNode("employee", attrs = c(ID = df1[[i,"ID"]]), close = FALSE))
```

Or

```
lapply(df1, function(x) lapply(appNames, function(v) xml$addNode(j, df[i, j])))
```

Not sure how to get to the same `XML` output using lapply

Comment: What do you mean by "thematically"?

Comment: Hi @ScottHunter, sorry for confusion. With thematically I just wanted to hint to the topic where I would like to use that function on lists. It could be of course any other topic. I though it makes sense to make a reproducible example within a topic.

Comment: but your `df1` is a list of `data.frame`s so not sure what you expect to win? Also the result will we a list? So I guess you can not just append or update an element outside of `lapply` (but this might be wrong).

Comment: Hi @drmariod, thank you for the hint. Perhaps there are better approaches. I just thought that may perform better on a large `.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider scanning csv by line to avoid any dataframe. On small documents, this might not be better option but on larger ones it may help and you avoid loading entire csv into memory. Also, below creates XML in a different approach with `newXMLDoc()`, `newXMLNode`, and `addAttribtues()` methods.

```
file <- "/path/to/file.csv"

# FIND NUMBER OF LINES (SKIP IF # OF ROWS IS KNOWN)
con <- file(description=file, open="r")
flines <- 0
while((linesread <- length(readLines(con, n=-1L, warn=FALSE))) > 0){
   flines <- flines + linesread
}
close(con)

doc = newXMLDoc()                                                    # INITIATE XML DOC
root = newXMLNode("Document", doc = doc)                             # DEFINE ROOT

# SCAN BY LINES
con <- file(description=file, open="r")
for(i in 1:flines) {
   tmp <- scan(file=con, nlines=1, what = list("","","",""), sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
   names(tmp) <- c('ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Age')  

   empNode = newXMLNode("employee", parent = root)                   # EMPLOYEE NODE
   addAttributes(empNode, id = tmp$ID)                               # ID ATTRIB 

   for (j in 2:length(tmp)){        
     data <- newXMLNode(names(tmp)[j], tmp[[j]], parent = empNode)   # CHILDREN
  }      
}
close(con)
```